# Electromagnetic loop

Tags: homework-and-exercises, electromagnetism, magnetic-fields

A circular Loop of radius R is bent along a diameter and given a shape as shown in the figure one of the semicircles (KNM) lies in the x-z plane and the other one (KLM)in the y-z plane with their centres at the origin. Current I is flowing through each of the semicircles as shown in the figure.

The problem that I have with this is that I have to find the magnetic field at the origin due to both the semicircles, I was able to calculate the magnitude of the magnetic field but I want help with finding the direction of magnetic field.
https://i.stack.imgur.com/uPyAh.jpg

Answer (score 1):

The magnetic field due to the semicircle in the y-z plane will point in the negative x direction and the field due to the semicircle in the x-z plane will point in the positive y direction. So, the net field at the origin will point at an angle $\theta$= 3$\pi$/4 from the +x-axis.

Comment: Can you please explain why is it so?

Comment: Use the Biot-Savart law, and integrate through the semi-circle--that will give you the magnetic field at the center of a semi-circular current. A Google search of "magnetic field at center due to semicircular current" should give you the complete integration.